# mysql database running very very slow

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have written a web application, (my first one) which is now running very very slow some of the ajax '$post's are taking up to 40 seconds.

I cannot supply the entire code for the site as it would take up too much space. I need to re factor it so that is runs faster.

when the website loads it does around 7 calls 7 scripts at the same time, all of which are retrieving data from a mysql database.

Q1 can you create a database queue in php (like fmdatabase.queue in obj-c)? so that there is one connection to the db and the call happen one after the other

the database has around 1 million points in it (which I was told should not lead to performance issues). I am using mysql not mysqli from the reading that I have done I wont see an improvement in speed from changing to mysqli. Is this right?

here is my database creating script:

```
$TripsData = "
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trips_data (
        id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        userid INT(10),
        tripid INT,
        gmttimestamp BIGINT,
        latitude DOUBLE(24,20),
        longitude DOUBLE(24,20),
        altitude DOUBLE(24,20),
        accuracy DOUBLE(24,20),
        speed DOUBLE(24,20),
        species INT,
        killcount INT,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) TYPE =MYISAM
";
```

and here is one of my scripts for getting user data

```
<?php
include ('header.php');
$userid=isloggedin();
if(isset($_POST['tripid'])){
$tripid=$_POST['tripid'];
$tripidbool=true;
}else{
  $tripidbool=false;
}
  if(isset($_POST['gamebook'])){$gamebookbool=true;}else{$gamebookbool=false;}
  if(isset($_POST['bounds'])){$bounds=$_POST['bounds'];$boundsboo=true;         }else{$boundsboo=false;}

if($tripidbool&&!$boundsboo){

    $totaldistanceinm=getTotalDistanceInM($userid, $tripid);        
echo '<tr><td> Distance Traveled </td><td> '.number_format(($totaldistanceinm/1000),2).' Km ('.number_format(($totaldistanceinm/1000)*(0.62137),2).' miles)</td></tr>';

     $query="SELECT MIN(gmttimestamp),
         MAX(gmttimestamp),
         AVG(speed), 
         SUM(killcount)
        from trips_data WHERE tripid=$tripid AND userid=$userid";   
     $result=mysql_query($query)or die(' '.mysql_error());
     $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);


echo'<tr><td>Start Time </td><td> '. date('H:i',$row[0]).'</td></tr>'; 

echo '<tr><td>Finish Time </td><td> '. date('H:i',$row[1]).'</td></tr>';

    $dur=  $row[1]-$row[0];
    if($dur!==0)
    {
        $hrs=($dur-($dur%3600))/3600;
        $mins=((($dur%3600)-($dur%60))/60);
        echo '<tr><td>Duration</td><td>'.$hrs.' Hours '.$mins.' Mins </td></tr> ';
    }

$totalk= $row[3];
echo '<tr><td>Total Kills</td><td>'.$totalk .'</td></tr>';
if($dur!==0)
    {
        echo '<tr><td>Kills/Hour</td><td>'.number_format(($totalk*3600/$dur),2).'</td></tr>';
    }

$total=$row[2];
echo '<tr><td>Avg Speed m/s</td><td>'.number_format($total,2).'</td></tr>';

    $query="SELECT SUM(gmttimestamp) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND tripid=$tripid AND speed>0";
$res=mysql_query($query) or die(' '.mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $timeMoving=$row[0];

    $query="SELECT SUM(gmttimestamp) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND tripid=$tripid AND speed=0";
$res=mysql_query($query) or die(' '.mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $timeNotMoving=$row[0];

    $toatltime=$timeMoving+$timeNotMoving;

    echo '<tr><td>%Time Moving/Stationary</td><td>'.number_format(($timeMoving/$toatltime)*100,2).'/'.number_format(($timeNotMoving/$toatltime)*100,2).'</td></tr>';
   // SELECT sum(trips_data.killcount), trips_data.species,masterspecies.species from trips_data join masterspecies WHERE tripid=335 AND userid=1 AND NOT killcount=0

$query="SELECT sum(trips_data.killcount) as kills,
        trips_data.species as species_id,
        masterspecies.species
            FROM trips_data
            JOIN masterspecies ON masterspecies.speciesidno = trips_data.species
            WHERE tripid =$tripid
            AND userid =$userid
            AND NOT killcount =0
            GROUP BY trips_data.species
            LIMIT 0 , 30";
$res=mysql_query($query)or die('87'.mysql_error());

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
    $species=$row['species_id'];
    $SpeciesName="";

    if($species<0){
        $species*=-1;
        $SpeciesName="Seen ";

    }
    $SpeciesName.=$row['species'];
    $totalkills=$row['kills'];

    echo '<tr><td>Total '.$SpeciesName.'s</td><td> '.$totalkills.' </td></tr>';
}

 }
 elseif ($boundsboo&&!$tripidbool){
    $minlat=$_POST['minlat'];
    $maxlat=$_POST['maxlat'];
    $minlong=$_POST['minlon'];
    $maxlong=$_POST['maxlon'];

    $latlon=getCenterPointForBox($minlat, $minlong, $maxlat, $maxlong);
    $farmerId=  getFarmerIdForCenterPoint($latlon[0], $latlon[1]);

    if($farmerId)
    {
        $where=getWhereClauseForFarmersBoundaries(getBoundaryBoxesForFarmer($farmerId));
        $query="SELECT DISTINCT tripid FROM trips_data WHERE (".$where .") AND userid=$userid order by gmttimestamp desc";

    }  else {
       $query="SELECT DISTINCT tripid FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid 
        AND latitude BETWEEN $minlat AND $maxlat 
        AND longitude BETWEEN $minlong AND $maxlong "; 
    }


$res=mysql_query($query) or die(' '.$query.' '.mysql_error());
$totaldistanceinm=0;
    $number=mysql_num_rows($res);

    $dur=0;
for($a=0;$a<$number;$a++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $ctripid=$row[0];

    $longprev=0;
    $latprev=0;
    $longdegstometers=10000000/90;
    $latdestom=0;


    $query_1="SELECT gmttimestamp,latitude, longitude FROM trips_data WHERE tripid=$ctripid AND userid=$userid ORDER BY gmttimestamp";
    $resa=mysql_query($query_1)or die(' '.mysql_error().$query_1);
    for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($resa);$i++){
        $rowa=mysql_fetch_assoc($resa);
        $long=$rowa['longitude'];
        $lat=$rowa['latitude'];
        if($i==0){
                            $st=$rowa['gmttimestamp'];
            $longprev=$long;
            $latprev=$lat;
            $latdestom=cos($long)*$longdegstometers;
        }
        if($i>=1){
            $dlongM=($longprev-$long)*$longdegstometers;
            $dlatM=($latprev-$lat)*$latdestom;
            $distance=sqrt(($dlatM*$dlatM)+($dlongM*$dlongM));
            $totaldistanceinm+=$distance;
            $longprev=$long;
            $latprev=$lat;
                            $et=$rowa['gmttimestamp'];
        }

    }
            $dur+=($et-$st);


    }

echo '<tr><td>Total Distance Traveled </td><td> '.number_format(($totaldistanceinm/1000),2).
' Km ('.number_format(($totaldistanceinm/1000)*(0.62137),2).' miles)</td></tr>';
$hrs=($dur-($dur%3600))/3600;
$mins=((($dur%3600)-($dur%60))/60);
echo '<tr><td>Total Contact</td><td>'.$hrs.' Hours '.$mins.' Mins </td></tr> ';
echo '<tr><td>Total Number of Trips</td><td>'.$number.'  </td></tr> ';

if(!$where)$where=" latitude BETWEEN $minlat AND $maxlat 
        AND longitude BETWEEN $minlong AND $maxlong ";
$query="SELECT DISTINCT species FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND killcount>0 AND ".$where ." ";
$re_sp=  mysql_query($query) or die(''.  mysql_error());
    for($i=0;$i<  mysql_num_rows($re_sp);$i++)
    {

    $row=  mysql_fetch_array($re_sp);
    $species=$row[0];
            if($species==0){continue;}
    $SpeciesName="";

            $iiquery="SELECT SUM(killcount) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid
      AND species=$species AND (".$where.") ";

    $iires=mysql_query($iiquery) or die('196 '.mysql_error());
    $iirow=mysql_fetch_array($iires);
    $totalkills=$iirow[0];

    if($species<0){
        $species*=-1;
        $SpeciesName="Seen ";

    }

    $iquery="SELECT species FROM masterspecies WHERE speciesidno=$species";
    $ires=mysql_query($iquery) or die('191 '.mysql_error());
    $irow=mysql_fetch_array($ires);
    $SpeciesName.=$irow[0];



    echo '<tr><td>Total '.$SpeciesName.'s</td><td> '.$totalkills.' </td></tr>';
}

}


if($gamebookbool){
$longprev=0;
$latprev=0;
$longdegstometers=10000000/90;
$latdestom=0;
$totaldistanceinm=0;

$query="SELECT MIN(gmttimestamp) from trips_data WHERE userid=$userid";
$result=mysql_query($query)or die(' '.mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$st=$row[0];
$date=date("j:F",$st);
echo'<tr><td> First Trip </td><td> '.$date.'</td></tr>';

  //for all trips
    $allTripsForHunter=allTripsForHunter($userid);
    $yearDistance=0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($allTripsForHunter);$i++){
$query="SELECT latitude, longitude FROM trips_data WHERE tripid=$allTripsForHunter[$i] AND userid=$userid ORDER BY gmttimestamp";

 $res=mysql_query($query)or die(' '.mysql_error());
i f(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){    
    for($i=0;$i<mysql_num_rows($res);$i++){
     $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $long=$row['longitude'];
    $lat=$row['latitude'];
    if($i==0){
        $longprev=$long;
        $latprev=$lat;
        $latdestom=cos($long)*$longdegstometers;
    }
    if($i>=1){
        $dlongM=($longprev-$long)*$longdegstometers;
        $dlatM=($latprev-$lat)*$latdestom;
        $distance=sqrt(($dlatM*$dlatM)+($dlongM*$dlongM));
        $totaldistanceinm+=$distance;
        $longprev=$long;
        $latprev=$lat;
        }
    }
            $yearDistance+=$totaldistanceinm;
        }
    }
echo '<tr><td> Distance Traveled </td><td> '.number_format(($yearDistance/1000),2).' Km ('.number_format(($yearDistance/1000)*(0.62137),2).' miles)</td></tr>';


    $yearDuration=0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($allTripsForHunter);$i++){
        $query="SELECT MIN(gmttimestamp) from trips_data WHERE tripid=$allTripsForHunter[$i] AND userid=$userid";   
        $result=mysql_query($query)or die(' '.mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $st=$row[0];
        $starttime=date('H:i',$row[0]);

        $query="SELECT MAX(gmttimestamp) from trips_data WHERE tripid=$allTripsForHunter[$i] AND userid=$userid";
        $result=mysql_query($query)or die(' '.mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $et=$row[0];
        $starttime=date('H:i',$row[0]); 

        $dur=($et-$st);
        $yearDuration+=$dur;
    }
    $days=($yearDuration-($yearDuration%86400))/86400;
    $hrs=(($yearDuration%86400)-($yearDuration%3600))/3600;
$mins=((($yearDuration%3600)-($yearDuration%60))/60);

    echo '<tr><td>Duration</td><td>'.$days.' Days '.$hrs.' Hours '.$mins.' Mins </td></tr> '; 

    $query="SELECT SUM(killcount) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid";
$res=mysql_query($query) or die(' '.mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$totalk=$row[0];
echo '<tr><td>Total Kills</td><td>'.$totalk.'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>Kills/Hour</td><td>'.number_format(($totalk*3600/$yearDuration),2).'</td></tr>';

$query="SELECT DISTINCT species from trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND NOT killcount=0";
$res=mysql_query($query)or die('87'.mysql_error());
$number=mysql_num_rows($res);

for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++){
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

    $species=$row['species'];
    $SpeciesName="";

            $iiquery="SELECT SUM(killcount) FROM trips_data WHERE userid=$userid AND species=$species";
    $iires=mysql_query($iiquery) or die('107 '.mysql_error());
    $iirow=mysql_fetch_array($iires);
    $totalkills=$iirow[0];

            if($species<1){
        $species*=-1;
        $SpeciesName="Seen ";

    }

    $iquery="SELECT species FROM masterspecies WHERE speciesidno=$species";
    $ires=mysql_query($iquery) or die(' '.mysql_error());
    $irow=mysql_fetch_array($ires);
    $SpeciesName.=$irow[0];



    echo '<tr><td>Total '.$SpeciesName.'s</td><td> '.$totalkills.' </td></tr>';
}



}
?>
```

Comment: First of all you need to profile your application and database to find the bottleneck. Then you can run to conclusions where you need to refactor/optimize the code. Until that information provided, your question should not be asked in this manner because bottlenecks can be at many different places, and basing your decisions on others that have told you something is not an issue does not help here much. Profile your application, then ask how to improve a certain place. http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler http://derickrethans.nl/talks.html

Comment: Your variables such as `$minlat` are injected straight into SQL without untainting, so this application may be hacked pretty quickly. If you are using this old database library, _always_ escape your user inputs! Look at `mysql_real_escape_string` in the manual.

Comment: Drop the mysql libs and learn to use pdo: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which I was told should not lead to performance issues

Quite contrary. When used as is, it certainly will. One have to design their queries and database properly to avoid performance issues.

You have to optimize your queries.

1. Run them all in console
2. Note the execution time.
3. Take most slow one and run it, perpended with word `EXPLAIN`
4. Study the output and ask questions about it
5. Repeat until done.